# Erro ao tentar setar a propriedade MissingSchemaAction de NpgsqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, ado.net

Estou tentando setar a propriedade `MissingSchemaAction` de um objeto `NpgsqlDataAdapter`, mas o Visual Studio está reclamando dizendo que a propriedade não existe.

Olhei no [github](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/dev/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlDataAdapter.cs) do projeto e vi que `NpgsqlDataAdapter` herda de `DbDataAdapter`, onde a [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx) mostra que possui a propriedade que eu estou tentando setar.

Se `NpgsqlDataAdapter` herda de `DbDataAdapter`, por que não estou conseguindo setar essa propriedade?

[image: SS]

Comment: Pode ser que esteja usando um objeto mas estar pensando que está usando outro. Precisa de mais detalhes de como está isso.

Comment: Vou editar e postar um print do código

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foi o que eu imaginei, com a *screenshot* do IDE deu pra ver que está usando a variável errada ou tentando usar uma propriedade não disponível para esta variável. `npgsqlCommand` é uma variável do tipo `NpgsqlCommand` e este tipo não tem esta propriedade mesmo. Esta propriedade estará disponível na variável `npgsqlDataAdapter` se é o que deseja. Ou seja, parece ser só um erro de digitação.

Comment: Baraio, veio, é mesmo. Não percebi.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva não sei se você percebeu que você pode votar em tudo no site. Eu noto que você aceita a resposta mas não costuma votar nela. Pode ser que não goste de fazer isto, mas se não sabe que são ações diferentes fica a informação. E repito, você pode votar em tudo o que acha interessante no site. E tem muita coisa legal que pode ajudar aprender coisas novas. Veja o [tour].